# Strange Android Soft Keyboard Issue

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm writing an activity, which has lots of EditText.

Their inputType are numericDecimal. Like this:  [Before I click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NENiP.png)

Now, I want to hide the soft keyboard when clicking somewhere other than the EditTexts, so I put:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View mView) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService
            (Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

After I click somewhere else, the numericDecimal soft keyboard do disappear. **HOWEVER**, there is still a common soft keyboard without autocompletion left on the screen, and I have absolutely no clue where does this come from. Showing here: [After I click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd88G.png)

So how to hide them all? Common ways on Internet don't work, I tried them all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Turns out the weird keyboard problem occurs due to focusableintouchmode. Disabling this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public static void setupUI(final View view, final Activity activity) {

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(activity, view);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupUI(innerView, activity);
        }
    }
}

    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity, View searchET) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchET.getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Call the setupUI function and pass the parent Layout in your activity. It will make sure that whenever you click out of your editText it will close the keyboard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This indeed solved 90% of the problem. But, it only works after the first click, which means after the first click, the weird common soft keyboard still appears.

Comment: One thing you can try more is :
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" in the parent layout of activity and then in onCreate call parentLayout.requestFocus();